# Is it possible to play DayZ on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: technical-issues, ubuntu, dayz-standalone

Hi I just installed non Steam version of DayZ into my Ubuntu 20.04 OS but I can't play it.

I heard that there is a program called Proton that is allowing play games or run programs made for Windows on Linux distros but I am not very familiar with it. I would like to play DayZ on Ubuntu without that proton. Do you think if is that possible? Thanks for your answers and advices.

Comment: Wasn't DayZ only sold on Steam? What's non-Steam version of DayZ? If you're asking about pirated games, this post will likely be closed soon.

Comment: Yeah, it's Steam only, so this must be a no-Steam crack.

Comment: @Skye-AT I got it from friend but he told me it is.from steam he just downloaded it from there. But that is not important. If he pirated it I will buy a copy myself I just wanna to test it how it will run on ubuntu and I wanna see if I will like it.

Comment: @Leviathan That isn't how it works. Even if your friend legitimately bought the copy from Steam, that doesn't mean anyone can play that copy(if it can what's the point of copy protection?). Anyway, you can [request refund](https://help.steampowered.com/en/faqs/view/784C-923B-A4A1-C825) if you didn't like game, I'd advise you buy a copy.

Comment: ...Or, maybe not. [DayZ Standalone](https://store.steampowered.com/app/221100/DayZ/) doesn't support Linux.

Comment: @Skye-AT I heard it is possible but with that Proton program or steam I was just curious if it is possible to run it without proton or steam on ubuntu

Comment: Even if I don't have any chips in this game's success, I would strongly recommend you buy the game via Steam. Since its an only online game, you would probably pretty quickly banned. Also, support the creators of what you play. But since the question is not straight up about hacking the game (its main subject is making it work in Ubuntu), i'll allow it.

Answer (score 2):

There is ProtonDB, a database which tracks Proton compatibility:

[DayZ Standalone Proton DB Entry](https://www.protondb.com/app/221100)

Answer (score 1):

If your computer is older than 2 years and has a AMD chip in it, then you cannot play because of AMD lack of support for Linux drivers.

If you do have a AMD chip that is new, then you are stuck with the Ubuntu version that has working Linux drivers.

Comment: It is notebook Dell Latitude E6420 I suppouse it is like 10 years old and it has Intel processor